# How to remotely backup folders on stolen Android?

Tags: security, backup, lost-phone

Most Android anti-theft apps can backup photos and text messages, but is there any app that can be installed through the web version of Google Play that can give me access to my folders and files to backup online if the phone is connected to WiFi?

Comment: The `lost-phone` tag you've used might include the key. Please follow up to [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/lost-phone/info), which includes a few helpful links.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a Dropbox account, you can use [Dropsync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync) to select which folders you want to sync to the Cloud.

I'm sure there are other solutions, but this is one thing you can consider.

Comment: Thanks geffchang, but how about a stolen phone that doesn't have DropSync on it?

Comment: @Qattaj I can't help you there, since I don't know. All I know is that some anti-theft apps let you WIPE / format the phone remotely. But if you needed an app to use AFTER the phone was stolen, I think that's too late. Anti-theft apps should be installed before the phone is gone; the same goes for Dropsync.

Comment: If you synchronized your device with gmail account, then login on your gmail, and check there for data.

Answer (score -1):

You can’t and you shouldn’t be able to either. Lost means lost. It would be a huge security vulnerability if you could arbitrarily extract files from the device remotely. The time for backing up has come and gone.

Comment: Why would it be a security vulnerability? The device has an authorized Google account and OP wants to use the same account to remotely install apps in his device to get hold of certain data. What's wrong in that? That's the feature of Play Store.